# Do we need a "Consult a Doctor" notice?

Tags: discussion

I've seen a few questions where people are essentially asking for medical advice. An online Q&A site is clearly not the best place for this and they should always consult a doctor.

Might it be a good idea to have a notice on the front page, similar to the "Consult a Lawyer" notice on Law.SE to make it clear that this site is for academic and educational use only?

Like this:
[image: Law SE]

Comment: We already have that notice under a custom close reason.. "*Personal medical questions and health advice are off-topic on Biology. We cannot safely answer questions for your specific situation and you should always consult a doctor for medical advice.*"

Comment: Aye, I didn't realise that was there. However, as well as a close reason I think it might be useful to have the notice so people are aware of it and don't ask the questions in the first place, or, reframe it into an academic perspective which benefits everyone

Comment: I think it's pretty clear in the help and other places. All in all, I think we get an incredibly low number of medical questions compared to how often people have medical questions. I think the ones that get through are just because some people won't pay attention no matter how hard you inform them.

Comment: Maybe, it's just an idea, because it's a relatively minor change to the site. If people don't feel like we need it fair enough. I've been on SO for a while but I'm new here so wouldn't want to throw my weight around.

Comment: I second WYSIWYG's and Bryan's thoughts. The homework questions a more often occurring issue I guess for that matter. But the Help Center is quite explicit about both of these.

Comment: Fair enough then

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273797/151385